# how to use java script to display url photo

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
fetch("wig1.json").then(
            res=>{
                res.json().then(
                    data=>{
                        console.log(data);
                        if(data.length > 0){
                            var tmp = '';
                            data.forEach((u)=>{
                                tmp +="<tr>";
                                tmp += "<td><img src="+u.PLink +"></td>"
                                tmp += "<td>"+u.Name+"</td>";
                                tmp += "<td> <a href="+u.link+">here</a></td>";
                                tmp += "<td>$"+u.Nprice+"</td>";
                                tmp += "<td>$"+u.Oprice+"</td></tr>";
                            })
                            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = tmp;
                        };
                    }
                )
            }
        )
```

I have the picture url inside my json file and I am going to display the picture using javascript in my html
Yet, after I run my code the picture become a picture icon
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you're getting an "Icon" that means that the server could not respond with your actual image. Make sure the path to your image is correct. `u.PLink` might not be what you think

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok. check your image urls.

```js
fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users").then(
    res => {
        res.json().then(
            data => {
                data = data.data
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    var tmp = '';
                    data.forEach((u) => {
                        tmp += "<tr>";
                        tmp += "<td><img src=" + u.avatar + "></td>"
                        tmp += "<td>" + u.first_name + "</td>";
                        tmp += "<td>" + u.last_name + "</td>";
                        tmp += "</td>";
                    });
                    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = tmp;
                };
            }
        )
    }
)
```

```html
<table id="data"></table>
```

I used [`ReqRes`](https://reqres.in/) apis that's why I added `data = data.data`.

Comment: It still not work that the console show: (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier) even that I change to display the image stored on localhost